# Sqlite3 cannot correctly query a UTF-8 string?

Tags: python, encoding, sqlite

I'm having a lot of trouble using python's sqlite3 library with UTF-8 strings. I need this encoding because I am working people's names, in my database.

My SQL schema for the desired table is:

```
CREATE TABLE senators (id integer, name char);
```

I would like to do the following in Python (ignore the very ugly way I wrote the select statement. I did it this way for debugging purposes):

```
statement = u"select * from senators where name like '" + '%'+row[0]+'%'+"'"
c.execute(statement)
```

row[0] is the name of each row in a file that has this type of entry:

```
Dário Berger,1
Edison Lobão,1
Eduardo Braga,1
```

While I have a non empty result for names like Eduardo Braga, any time my string has UTF-8 characters, I get a null result.

I have checked that my file has in fact been saved with UTF-8 encoding (Microsoft Notepad). On a Apple mac, in the terminal, I used the PRAGMA command in the sqlite3 shell to check the encoding:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding;
UTF-8
```

Does anybody have an idea what I can do here?

EDIT - Complete example:
Python script that creates the databases, and populates with initial data from senators.csv ([file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzOQKdH4sC1gdXMzTjI3Rnlsa28/view?usp=sharing)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3 
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect('senators.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE senators (id integer, name char)''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE polls (id integer, senator char, vote integer, FOREIGN KEY(senator) REFERENCES senators(name))''')

with open('senators.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f_csv:
        c.execute(u"INSERT INTO senators VALUES(?,?)", (row[1], row[0]))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Script that populates the polls table, using Q1.txt ([file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzOQKdH4sC1gb29Ka1dCVk5qaWs/view?usp=sharing)).

```
import csv
import sqlite3
import re
import glob

conn = sqlite3.connect('senators.db')
c = conn.cursor()

POLLS = {
    'senator': 'votes/senator/Q*.txt',
    'deputee': 'votes/deputee/Q*.txt',
}

s_polls = glob.glob(POLLS['senator'])
d_polls = glob.glob(POLLS['deputee'])

for poll in s_polls:
    m = re.match('.*Q(\d+)\.txt', poll)
    poll_id = m.groups(0)

    with open(poll, encoding='utf-8') as p:
        f_csv = csv.reader(p)
        for row in f_csv:
            c.execute(u'SELECT id FROM senators WHERE name LIKE ?', ('%'+row[0]+'%',))
            data = c.fetchone()
            print(data) # I should not get None results here, but I do, exactly when the query has UTF-8 characters.
```

Note the file paths, if you want to test these scripts out.

Comment: Don't use string manipulation on SQL queries! Take a look at the big warning boxes in the Python docs and use query parameters instead.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I was doing it using parameters, this was just to debug to make sure I wasn't making a mistake in the string interpolation, since I was and still am getting weird results.

Answer (score 3):

Ok guys,

After a lot of trouble, I found out that the problem was that the encodings, all though were both considered UTF-8, were still different anyways. The difference was that while the database was decomposed UTF-8 (ã = a + ~), my input was in precomposed form (one code for the ã character).

To fix it, I had to convert all my input data to the decomposed form.

```
 from unicodedata import normalize
 with open(poll, encoding='utf-8') as p:
        f_csv = csv.reader(p)
        for row in f_csv:
            name = normalize("NFD",row[0])
            c.execute(u'SELECT id FROM senators WHERE name LIKE ?', ('%'+name+'%',))
```

See this [article](http://jktauber.com/articles/python-unicode-ancient-greek/), for some excellent information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SQLite docs](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

> Important Note: SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression `'a' LIKE 'A'` is TRUE but `'æ' LIKE 'Æ'` is FALSE.

Also, use query parameters. Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: See my comment to @ColonelThirtyTwo, about query parameters. This is not a case of upper/lower case distinction. When I copy the value inside the database: for example Sérgio Petecão, the query works, but when I receive the same string, with apparently slightly different encoding, Sérgio Peteção, it does not work!

Comment: @jhc `SELECT 'Edison Lobão' LIKE '%Edison Lobão%'` returns 1 for me. Please create a [mcve] exact schema, test data, query, and results.

Comment: please refer to EDIT I just posted.